# Prove Jensen’s inequality: $F(\frac{1}{μ(X)}\int f \,dμ) ≤ \frac{1}{μ(X)} \int F(f)\,dμ.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,A,μ)$ be a finite measure space, and let $F : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function with second derivative $F'' > 0$. Let $f \in L_1(\mu)$ be real-valued. Prove Jensen’s inequality:

$$F\left(\frac{1}{μ(X)}\int f \,d\mu\right) \le \frac{1}{\mu(X)} \int F(f)\,d\mu.$$

I am sure this isn't too difficult, but I am not so sure how to begin, and I can't find the proof in this context online.  I would appreciate some help.  It a practice qual prob.  Thanks.

Comment: The proof of Jensen's inequality for probability measures is in a *huge* number of books (Rudin, Royden, Folland, Garnett, .....). Then just notice that $d\mu/\mu(X)$ is a probability measure.

Comment: there is a proof on wikipedia... you just wrote down the probability form...

Comment: Why is existence of 2nd derivative relevant at all?

Answer (score 2):

$F^{\prime\prime}>0$ means the function is convex (if $a<b<c$ are such that $\frac{F(a)-F(b)}{a-b}>\frac{F(c)-F(b)}{c-b}$ then apply mean value theorem twice to find that there exist a point where $F^{\prime\prime}<0$). The rest of this answer is just going to be standard proof of Jensen's inequality.

Let $E=\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int fd\mu$. Since $F$ is convex, there exist a slope $m$ such that $F(x)\geq F(E)+m(x-E)$ (set $m=\inf\limits_{x>0}\frac{F(x)-F(E)}{x-E}$, then existence of $m$ and the fact that it works are both consequence of convexity). Then $\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int F(f)d\mu\geq\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int F(E)+m(f-E)d\mu=\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int F(E)d\mu+\frac{m}{\mu(X)}fd\mu-\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int mEd\mu=F(E)+mE-mE=F(E)$

Answer (score 0):

$$F(x)=F(a)+\int_a^x F'(t) \, dt=F(a)+F'(a)(x-a)+\int_a^x \int_a^t F''(s)\,ds\,dt$$

$$\ge F(a)+F'(a)(x-a).$$

Now take $a=\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int f\,d\mu$ and $x=f(u)$ and then integrate over $X$ to get:

$$\int F(f) \, d\mu\ge\mu(X)F\left(\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int f \, d\mu\right)$$